# Changing foreach statement to display current user's table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a leaderboard that i am making but am wanting to display the current user rank on the top of my page, i have been trying to make the following code to work

```
              <?
if(! defined('BASEPATH') ){ exit('Unable to view file.'); }
$sql = $db->Query("SELECT uid, SUM(`total_clicks`) AS `clicks` FROM `user_clicks` GROUP BY uid ORDER BY `clicks` DESC");
$tops = $db->FetchArrayAll($sql);

$j = 0;
foreach($tops as $top){
    $j++;
    $user = $db->QueryFetchArray("SELECT id,login,email,country,coins FROM `users` WHERE `id`='".$top['uid']."'");
?>
<?=$user['login']?>
<?}?>
```

this returns all the usernames in a nice row i have tried the following

```
<?=$user['top']?>

<?=$user['j']?>
```

i understand its something to do with the foreach statement that needs to be changed but i also know i am missing something.

What i am trying to achieve is `Rank : 31`

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the rank directly in your query. Then you don't need a loop to calculate the rank

```
SELECT uid, 
       SUM(`total_clicks`) AS `clicks`,
       @rank := @rank + 1 as ranking
FROM `user_clicks`, (select @rank := 0) r
GROUP BY uid 
ORDER BY `clicks` DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply what would the php code to display it?<?=$user['rank']?>

Comment: This gives a number of 2 all the time with no matter who logs in